Snap and display a tooltip for the line graph instead of just the points
I have a straightforward line chart. With the default settings, I receive a tooltip that corresponds to a point in the data series.
Is there a way to display a tooltip for the current graph coordinates that are snapped to the line of the diagram, rather than just the points in the data series?

Yes, you can achieve this in Highcharts by overriding tooltip behaviour. By default, the tooltip snaps to the data points in the series. However, you can display a tooltip for the current graph coordinates snapped to the line by dynamically interpolating values between data points based on the mouse position. To do so, you can add the mousemove listener to the chart container, and based on it's position, calculate mouse coords on the chart and feed them into the tooltip.
const tooltipX = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(xValue);
const tooltipY = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(yValue, true);

chart.tooltip.label.attr({
    text: `X: ${Highcharts.numberFormat(xValue, 2)}<br>Y: ${Highcharts.numberFormat(yValue, 2)}`,
    x: tooltipX + 10,
    y: tooltipY - 10
}).show();

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfLam342/
